# Python, scatter plot for all independent variables

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to make a method which will produce scatter plots for all independent variables in my dataset, but 
I have an error and I don't know why it appear in that case

```
class DataAnalysis():
  def __init__(self, X_train, X_test):
    self.X_train = X_train # Train set
    self.X_test = X_test # Test set

  def multi_scatter(self,x_list, y):
    length = np.ceil(len(x_list)/3).astype(int)
    for x in range(0, length):
      fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize = (20,10))
      fig.suptitle('Independent variables correlation with target')
      axs[0,0].scatter(self.X_train[x_list[x]], self.X_train[y])
      axs[0,0].set_title(x_list[x])
      axs[0,1].scatter(self.X_train[x_list[x+1]], self.X_train[y])
      axs[0,1].set_title(x_list[x+1])
      axs[0,2].scatter(self.X_train[x_list[x+2]], self.X_train[y])
      axs[0,2].set_title(x_list[x+2])
      x *= 3
      plt.show()
```

Here is an error i get:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-e8ff51256833> in <module>()
----> 1 analyser.multi_scatter(x_list=train_columns,y=target)

<ipython-input-30-fb0defddaef8> in multi_scatter(self, x_list, y)
      9       fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize = (20,10))
     10       fig.suptitle('Independent variables correlation with target')
---> 11       axs[0,0].scatter(ds_train['ExterQual'], ds_train['SalePrice'])
     12       axs[0,0].set_title(x_list[x])
     13       axs[0,1].scatter(self.X_train[x_list[x+1]], self.X_train[y])

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Thank You in advance for Your help

Comment: `axs[0]`, `axs[1]`, and `axs[2]` instead of `axs[0,0]`, `axs[0,1]`, and `axs[0,2]`.

Comment: Thanks, that solve this error, but I would like to have 3 plots in every row, so it would not be too long

Comment: I don't understand... you have one row with 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

While apparently the question has been solved in comments, another (simpler) way to be to use a more appropriate plotting library. For instance:

- [Pandas' scatter_matrix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.html)
- [Seaborn's pairplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html)
- [Altair's RepeatChart](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_matrix.html) and other powerful visualization libraries.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but i don't want to plot matrix of all variables combination I wants plots of all my independent vars ( list of x variables) and target variable (y). So my idea was to create a loop which make three plots in one row in every iteration, until my variables ends

Comment: @PawełMagdańskiYou can tell each of these what to plot against what.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have it, thank You for suggestions. Still have some troubles with labels, but I will figure that out

here is a code:

```
class DataAnalysis():
  def __init__(self, X_train, X_test):
    self.X_train = X_train # Train set
    self.X_test = X_test # Test set

  def multi_scatter(self,x_list, y):
    sns.set(style='whitegrid', rc={"grid.linewidth": 0.2})
    sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=2)  
    for x in range(0, len(x_list)):
      if x == 0 or x % 3:
        chart = sns.pairplot(data=self.X_train,
        y_vars=[y],
        x_vars=[x_list[x], x_list[x+1], x_list[x+2]],
        height = 10)
        plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
        plt.show()
      else:
        continue
```